# FragmentActivity vs managing Fragment using FragmentTransaction?

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

many tutorials on `Fragment` found on the web (like [this one](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)) use `FragmentActivity`. It seems to be the static way of using `Fragment`, as opposed to the dynamic way using `FragmentTransaction` to load `Fragment` s in a container in a normal `Activity`.

I'm using API 12 and `FragmentActivity` is not there (it's in `android.support.v4.app`).

So if I don't use the Android support package, I can only manage `Fragment` dynamically, right? Why has `FragmentActivity` disappeared?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It seems to be the static way of using Fragment, as opposed to the dynamic way using FragmentTransaction to load Fragment s in a container in a normal Activity.

That is completely wrong.

`FragmentActivity` is for use with the Android Support package, if you wish to use fragments prior to API Level 11. Both static (`<fragment>` in a layout) and dynamic (`FragmentTransaction`) fragments are supported both by `FragmentActivity` and by `Activity` (the latter only on API Level 11 and higher).

> I'm using API 12 and FragmentActivity is not there (it's in android.support.v4.app).

Add the Android Support package to your project. For example, from Eclipse, and right-click over the project, choose Android Tools > Add Support package from the context menu.

> So if I don't use the Android support package, I can only manage Fragment dynamically, right?

No, you can use static or dynamic fragments with `Activity` on API Level 11.

> Why has FragmentActivity disappeared?

It has not disappeared. For ease of use, they integrated the Android Support package JavaDocs into the main JavaDocs. Whenever you see a class in an `android.support` package, you know that it is from the Android Support package.